How to hypertune Conv2D and MaxPooling2D in CNN?
How to hypertune Conv2D and MaxPooling2D?
The codes below are using ANN model, can we use the same format of codes to optimize CNN?
#A. Tune First the Batch Size and Epoch
#A.1 Build the CNN Model for the Optimization Process
def classifier_optimization():
    classifier_optimization = Sequential()
    classifier_optimization.add(Dense(units = 7, kernel_initializer = "glorot_uniform", activation = "relu", input_dim = 12))
    classifier_optimization.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1))
    classifier_optimization.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = "glorot_uniform", activation = "relu"))
    classifier_optimization.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1))
    classifier_optimization.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = "glorot_uniform", activation = "sigmoid"))
    classifier_optimization.compile(optimizer = "sgd", loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
    return classifier_optimization

ann_model_optimization = KerasClassifier(model=classifier_optimization, verbose = 0)

#A.2 Import the GridSearchCV class 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

#A.3 To Set the Parameters to be optimized for the ANN Model
parameters = {"batch_size" : [50, 100, 150, 200, 250],
              "epochs" : [10, 50, 100, 200, 250]}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = ann_model_optimization, param_grid = parameters, scoring = "accuracy", cv = k_fold, n_jobs = -1)

grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_standard, Y)
print(grid_search)

#A.4 To View the result of the GridSearchCV
results = pd.DataFrame(grid_search.cv_results_) [["mean_test_score" , "std_test_score", "params"]]
print(results)

#A.5 To identify the best accuracy and the best features
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_

print("Best Accuracy Score:", best_accuracy)
print("Best Parameters:", best_parameters)

We've tried optimizing Sequential, Flatten, and Dense separately. Can you help optimize Conv2D and MaxPooling2D

I suggest utilizing Keras Tuner for efficient hyperparameter optimization. It
offers superior performance and flexibility compared to Grid Search CV. For a
practical demonstration with CNNs using keras tuner, please refer to the
attached gist.
